# Best way to filter on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am wondering what's the best and efficient way of checking if 3 out of 4 criteria are met while filtering in pandas.

target word: `Stevenson`

dataframe:

```
+-----------+
|   Names   |
+-----------+
| Smith     |
| Stevens   |
| Parker    |
| Stevenson |
| Dickson   |
| Greene    |
+-----------+
```

I need to filter this df to include words that have at least 3 out of 4 `bigrams = ["st", "te", "ev", "on"]` . I need it to include words `Stevens` and `Stevenson`. Then I calculate similiarity measure between my target word and the words filtered.

What I do now is creating all combinations of 3 out of 4 `[(st, te, ev), (st, ev, on), ....]` and filtering my dataframe with `df.Names.str.contains("st") & df.Names.str.contains("ev")` etc. Then I only leave the unique rows.

I feel this is not the most efficient way of doing it as I am wasting most of time on filtering and not on fuzzy matching (as I had expected). I am testing on df of size 100k but my real df is more than 1M rows. Any idea how to do it better? Binary search doesn't work for my real example.

Comment: it seems like boolean indexing is what you are looking for. It will be much more efficient. (http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/#boolean-indexing)

Comment: I am not sure if it is more efficient but can you test `df[sum([df['Names'].str.contains(pat) for pat in bigrams]) >= 3]`?

Comment: I think ayhan proposed a good solution. The only think i'd like to add is that the combination of apply + in can be faster than pandas str.contains (twice as fast in a case i had with approx. 1m rows)

Comment: @P.Tillmann Yes `df[sum([df['Names'].apply(lambda x: pat in x) for pat in bigrams]) >= 3]`  seems to be faster in my tests, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. (after a few edits)

```
bigrams = ["st", "te", "ev", "on"]
df['count'] = df.Names.apply(lambda x: sum([1 for v in bigrams if v in x]))
df[df['count'] >= 3].Names
```

Comment: took 1.32 ms on `df = DataFrame({'Names':['stevens','smith','parker','john','greene','dickson', 'harsh', 'steven','stack']})`

Comment: I am gonna try that and will report back. Seems much better (and cleaner) than mine.

Comment: @Adam thanks a lot! This idea is great. I have overcomplicated my process adding np.logical_and  and np.logical_or, whilst it could have been done so easily. The execution time difference is significant.

Comment: No problem. I'm gonna have to trust you on the execution time stuff as previously stated I didn't do any performance profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.apply`, if `datatype` of *Names* is `str`

```
df[df['Names'].apply(lambda x : ('st' in x) & ('ev' in x))]
```